# Range-based for loops and vectors in C++98

Tags: c++, for-loop, vector

I am trying to compile the code above and I am getting: range-based-for loops are not allowed in c++98 mode

```
int max_even = timer_table[0];
int max_odd = timer_table[1];
bool even = true;
for( int v : timer_table )
{
    if( even ) {
    if( v > max_even )
        max_even = v;
    } else {
    if( v > max_odd )
        max_odd = v;
    }
    even = ! even;
}

std::cout << "max even " << max_even << " max odd " << max_odd << std::endl;
```

Any way to compile it on `c++98`?

Comment: You generally can't use C++ standards newer than the compiler supports. If you *must* use C++98 standard, write C++98 standard code.

Comment: Change the loop to a regular iterator loop.

Comment: If you check e.g. [this range-for reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) you will see the equivalent using non-range-for.

Comment: @crashmstr: I disagree - if compiler complains that "**range-based-for loops** are not allowed in c++98 mode", it has to be aware of that syntax construction, which means that it, most probably, supports c++11, just needs to be allowed to make use of it. GCC, for example, has to be provided with `-std=c++11` switch.

Comment: @el.pescado Essentially it *won't* support it without the compiler flag. Plus, the question asks "how to make this work with C++98", not "how to make my compiler support C++11". So without turning on C++11 support, you *can't* compile C++11 code with only C++98 support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First approach is to replace it with regular `for` loop. For more precise answer we need to know how `timer_table` declared or where we can get its size.

```
int max_even = timer_table[0];
int max_odd = timer_table[1];
bool even = true;
int timer_table_size = sizeof(timer_table)/sizeof(timer_table[0]);
for( int i = 0, v = timer_table[0]; i < timer_table_size; ++i,  v = (i<timer_table_size)?timer_table[i]:0)
{
    if( even ) {
    if( v > max_even )
        max_even = v;
    } else {
    if( v > max_odd )
        max_odd = v;
    }
    even = ! even;
}

std::cout << "max even " << max_even << " max odd " << max_odd << std::endl;
```

Comment: This is not the same as the OP's loop.  `v` should be each element of `timer_table`

Comment: Oh, I see. I'll fix it

Answer (score 3):

Looks like your compiler tries to compile in `C++98`, which doesn't support range-based for loops by default (see el.pescado's comment below). You have two options:

1. Set your compiler to use C++11
2. Use a simple for loop like so:

   ```
   int max_even = timer_table[0]; 
   int max_odd = timer_table[1];
   bool even = true;
   for( int i = 2 ; i < table_length; i++ )
   {
       if( even ) {
         if( timer_table[i] > max_even )
         max_even = timer_table[i];
       } else {
         if( timer_table[i] > max_odd )
         max_odd = timer_table[i];
       }
       even = ! even;
   }

   std::cout << "max even " << max_even << " max odd " << max_odd << std::endl;
   ```

Comment: This is the best answer. When compiler says "range-based-for loops are not allowed in c++98 mode" it means it supports it, but not in default configuration. So the solution is to configure it to enable C++11 features. If compiler didn't support C++11, it would issue generic syntax error. Rewriting this loop in C++98 makes code worse, not better.

Comment: Thank you for the precision! I'll update my answer. What do you mean by "Rewriting this loop in C++98 makes code worse, not better"?

Comment: Range-based loops are much more concise and easier to read. Less verbose code ⇒ better code. That's my personal opinion, though.

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume that array `timer_table` has `N` elements.

In this case you can write

```
int max_even = timer_table[0];
int max_odd = timer_table[1];
bool even = true;

for( const int *p = timer_table + 2; p != timer_table + N; ++p )
{
    if( even ) {
    if( max_even < *p )
        max_even = *p;
    } else {
    if( max_odd < *p )
        max_odd = *p;
    }
    even = !even;
}

std::cout << "max even " << max_even << " max odd " << max_odd << std::endl;
```

In fact you can use any kind of loop that allows to traverse all elements of the array.:)

Answer (score 1):

To make the code work in C++98, you should use the iterator approach:

```
for( std::vector<int>::iterator i = timer_table.begin(); i != timer_table.end(); ++i)
{
    int v = *i;
    ...
```

Or if it is a plain array:

```
for(int *i = timer_table; i < sizeof(timer_table)/(sizeof(timer_table[0]); ++i)
{
    int v = *i;
    ...
```

Comment: How do you know `timer_table` is a vector?

Comment: One doesn't. But the other answers assume it is a plain array. How does one know that?

Comment: Or you could make your own begin functions and not assume but give the OP an answer that works in both cases.